# How to take item names off a list and use it in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two lists and I want to take item names from the list and use it to a loop. I want to take the name of dataframe from the df_compressed_list and plot a figure with two columns of that dataframe and then save that figure to a folder. It should take the name of the figure from the plot_image_list
Please see the codes below.

```
df_compressed_list= ['df_compressed_1','df_compressed_2','df_compressed_3','df_compressed_4','df_compressed_5','df_compressed_6','df_compressed_7','df_compressed_8','df_compressed_9','df_compressed_10','df_compressed_11','df_compressed_12','df_compressed_13','df_compressed_14']

plot_image_list= ['compressed_1','compressed_2','compressed_3','compressed_4','compressed_5','compressed_6','compressed_7','compressed_8','compressed_9','compressed_10','compressed_11','compressed_12','compressed_13','compressed_14']

for i in df_compressed_list:
    plt.figure(100,figsize=(10,5))
    plt.plot(i['time'], i['voltage'])
    for j in plot_image_list:
        plt.savefig('images\j.PNG')
    plt.close()
```

['time'] and ['voltage'] are columns names of a pandas dataframe.I already created dataframe with respective names. I tried the above code but it doesn't work. It shows

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What I want it to do is, it will take the name one by one from the list and put the name in         `plt.plot(i['time'], i['voltage'])`
So that it would look like this

```
plt.plot(df_compressed_1['time'], df_compressed_1['voltage'])
```

And

`plt.savefig('images\j.PNG')`
so that it would look like this

```
 plt.savefig('images\compressed_1.PNG')
```

In every iteration it should take the next name of df_compressed_list list and plot_image_list.
Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'am still not exactly sure want you trying to accomplish, but i think this may help you. Maybe you can just take the concept of this and rewrite it to fit your problem.

I created two pandas DataFrames `df1` and `df2` these could also be opened from a csv etc. with `df1 = pd.read_csv()` Then I put them into a list `df_list`.
Now i made a loop that loops over all of the DataFrames and saves the plot of the `voltage` over the `time` in a `figs` folder.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "voltage" : [0, 23, 44, 19, 7, 3],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "voltage" : [0, 200, 404, 200, 190, 150],
    }
)

df_list = [df1, df2]

for df_number in range(len(df_list)):
    fig = plt.figure(100, figsize=(10, 5))
    ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
    
    # df_list[index] -> df1 .. df2; df2["voltage"] -> [0, 200, 404, 200, 190, 150]
    ax.plot(df_list[df_number]["time"], df_list[df_number]["voltage"])
    fig.savefig("figs/figure{}.jpg".format(df_number))
```

The figs folder must be created manually. Look at pathlib for more info on working with filenames and paths.

Comment: Could you please take a look a at my edited post and tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Elements of `df_compressed_list` are *strings*, *not* dataframes.
2. Thus, the `i` in `for i in df_compressed_list:`, being an element of the list (*not* an index into `df_compressed_list`!), is a string.
3. Then, `df_compressed_list[i]` attempts to index the list with this string.
4. This an error since "list indices must be integers or slices, not str".

You could fix this by replacing `for i in df_compressed_list:` by `for i, _ in enumerate(df_compressed_list):`, but then there'd be more errors:

1. Elements of `df_compressed_list` are *strings*, *not* dataframes.
2. Thus, `df_compressed_list[i]` would be a *string*.
3. So, `df_compressed_list[i]['time']` would attempt to index this string with another string, `'time'`.
4. This is also an error because `string indices must be integers`, not `str`ings.

Comment: Is there any way I can achieve what I am trying to do? Please also have another look at my edited post for better explanation.

Comment: @Nazmul1001, `for i in collection:` iterates over elements of the collection. So `i` will be an _element_ of the collection, not an index. That's the reason your code doesn't work: this isn't how one iterates over indices of a collection. You could write `for i in range(len(collection))` to do this. Also, `'images\j.png'` is not how string interpolation works. You can use f-strings to do string interpolation/formatting. Also also, `df_compressed` is _still_ a list of strings, not dataframes, so there's no point in indexing into these strings. Please read a Python tutorial before writing code.